# Distance between two 3D points in R

Tags: r, euclidean-distance

I have two 2 points A(x,y,z) e B(x1,y1,z1).
I want to calculate the euclidean distance between these point at time1, time2, time3.

So, I have a matrix like this:

```
         x     y     z     x1     y1     z1    distance
time1    2     1     2      4      6      8       ?
time2    3     4     3      6      6      7       ?
time3    6     8     9      4      3      3       ?
```

As you can see above, I want to add a column (distance), in which I report the euclidean distance between A e B.

Have you any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: If you know the euclidian distance formula you can start with the first row yourself and then we can help you from there.

Answer (score 9):

You're looking for the `dist()` function:

```r
df <- read.table(header = TRUE, text = "
         x     y     z     x1     y1     z1
time1    2     1     2      4      6      8
time2    3     4     3      6      6      7
time3    6     8     9      4      3      3")

df$distance <- apply(df, 1, function(x) dist(matrix(x, nrow = 2, byrow = TRUE)))

df
#>       x y z x1 y1 z1 distance
#> time1 2 1 2  4  6  8 8.062258
#> time2 3 4 3  6  6  7 5.385165
#> time3 6 8 9  4  3  3 8.062258
```

From `help("dist")`:

> Description
>
> This function computes and returns the distance matrix computed by using the specified distance measure to compute the distances between the rows of a data matrix.
>
> Usage
>
> dist(x, method = "euclidean", diag = FALSE, upper = FALSE, p = 2)

So, if you give it a `m` matrix like

```r
2 1 2
4 6 8
```

`distance(m)` will calculate the euclidean distance between `c(2, 1, 2)` and `c(4, 6, 8)`. Then we can just apply to each row of your dataset the `dist()` function called on a matrix constructed from that row, where the first row of the new matrix is the `x`, `y`, and `z` observations for that row of your dataset, and the second row of the new matrix is the `x1`, `y1`, and `z1` observations for that row of your dataset.

Comment: I'm not sure if answering a question that obviously has neither research nor any trial-and-error behind it is the most sensible approach.